# Default constraint issue

Tags: sql-server, constraint, ddl, default-value

I have a table `TempTable` with one column having a default constraint

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TempTable] 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TempTable_Version]  
DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Version]
```

`Version` is defined as `decimal (18,1)`

Most of the time the value 1.00 is inserted into the column but in some cases its inserting a null value.

How we can identify if the constraint is failing or if there is some other issues causing this?

Answer (score 3):

> How we can identify if the constraint is failing or if there is some
>   other issues causing this?

The most likely cause is that a client is simply *inserting* a null, or updating the column to null, neither of which is prevented by a default constraint.

If you don't want nulls, just declare the Version column as NOT NULL, or add a check constraint.

Answer (score 2):

If you give the `ALTER TABLE` command while there are concurrent insertions, this could be possible, unless you set an high `ISOLATION LEVEL`. *After* the command has been issued, every new insertion will provide the correct default value.
If null values remain in the column after the initial `ALTER TABLE`, you can simply change them with an update, e.g.

```
UPDATE tempTable
SET Version = 1
WHERE Version IS NULL
```